# How to add '/' at the end of each DDl using dbms_metadata(SQL terminator )

Tags: oracle, ddl

In the [documentation for `dbms_metadata`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_metada.htm#i1019267), mentioned about `SQLTERMINATOR`:

> If `TRUE`, append a SQL terminator (`;` or `/`) to each DDL statement. Defaults to `FALSE`.

by this below step:

```sql
BEGIN
   DBMS_METADATA.set_transform_param (DBMS_METADATA.session_transform, 'SQLTERMINATOR', true);
END;
/
```

Default after enabled ';' is added at end of each DDL.

How can I add `/` instead of `;` at the end of the DDL using `dbms_metadata` or any possibility.

If I try overload method of `dbms_metadata.set_transform_param`, it errors out

```sql
BEGIN
  DBMS_METADATA.set_transform_param(
    DBMS_METADATA.session_transform, 'SQLTERMINATOR', '/'
  );
END;
/
```

````
  2    3    4  BEGIN
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-31600: invalid input value "/" for parameter SQLTERMINATOR in function
SET_TRANSFORM_PARAM
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SYS_ERROR", line 105
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_METADATA_INT", line 8844
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_METADATA_INT", line 10288
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_METADATA", line 8418
ORA-06512: at line 2```
````

Please can anybody help this?

As said in my one of the comments below , attaching the use case.
I want DDL to be added to file separated by '/' indicates end of ddl.

````
create table test (id number);
/
CREATE OR REPLACE EDITIONABLE PACKAGE "C##CLOUD$SERVICE"."MY_PACKAGE1" As
   M_VCSIZ_4K               CONSTANT PLS_INTEGER := 4000;

   procedure fun1(
     value number
   );
end my_package1;
/```

while importing I will get ddl and execute using 'execute immediate' mean
```execute immediate 'create table test (id number);' -- due to semi colon but success if no semi colon
execute immediate 'CREATE OR REPLACE EDITIONABLE PACKAGE "C##CLOUD$SERVICE"."MY_PACKAGE1" As
   M_VCSIZ_4K               CONSTANT PLS_INTEGER := 4000;

   procedure fun1(
     value number
   );
end my_package1;' -- works as it has semi colon but fails if no semicolon```

how can I get out of this situation and work for both the cases
````

Answer (score 0):

I think that what you want is wrong.

There are two terminators: semi-colon (`;`) and slash (`/`). However, they aren't "equal" as some DDL statements end with a colon, e.g.

```
create table test (id number);
```

It would work with a slash too:

```
create table test (id number)
/
```

But, `DBMS_METADATA` extracts PL/SQL as well, and these objects end with the `end;` and additional slash is required to execute those statements, e.g.

```
SQL> create procedure test is
  2  begin
  3    null;
  4  end;
  5  /           --> this; without it, procedure wouldn't be created, cursor
                     just keeps blinking (or, in SQL*Plus, you get number of 
                     subsequent lines (6, 7, 8, 9, ...)    
Procedure created.

SQL>
```

What you want is to have slash as a terminator, and that would lead to an error:

```
SQL> create procedure test is
  2  begin
  3    null;
  4  end/              --> "your" slash
  5  /                 --> PL/SQL block terminator

Warning: Procedure created with compilation errors.

SQL> show err
Errors for PROCEDURE TEST:

LINE/COL ERROR
-------- -----------------------------------------------------------------
4/4      PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "/" when expecting one of the
         following:
         ; <an identifier> <a double-quoted delimited-identifier>
         current delete exists prior <a single-quoted SQL string>
         The symbol "; was inserted before "/" to continue.

SQL>
```

Therefore, it depends on that particular DDL - some of them don't care about the terminator (such as `create table`), while PL/SQL objects raise an error if `sqlterminator` is wrongly set.

Comment: Thanks for replying. In my requirement I won't be including the terminator while execution. What I am doing is -> using get_ddl I will add DDL to a file , will each DDL separated by '/' indicating that is end of that DDL stmt. later I will use that file to import those DDL to other db. I will execute those ddl as execute immediate. So execute immediate of create table fails if we have semicolon at end but create package fails if we don't have semicolon at the end. Adding example of this in my actual question body

Comment: Why wouldn't you use Export (and then Import) **Data Pump** instead?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `execute immediate` doesn't require any terminator. As long as it allows only a single statement as input, there's no need to identify individual statements by terminator.

You may use the original code returned by `get_ddl` without terminators.

> ```
> create function f
> return number
> is
> begin
>   return null;
> end;/
> ```

> ```
> create table t(id int)
> ```

> ```
> create view v_ddl
> as
> select
>   dbms_metadata.get_ddl(
>     'FUNCTION',
>     'F'
>   ) as ddl_
> from dual
> union all
> select
>   dbms_metadata.get_ddl(
>     'TABLE',
>     'T'
>   ) as ddl_
> from dual
> ```

> ```
> select *
> from v_ddl
> ```
>
> ```
> | DDL_                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   |
> | :--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- |
> | <br>  CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION "FIDDLE_CGDJQPMDTXHHROBDNHLJ"."F" <br>return number<br>is<br>begin<br>  return null;<br>end;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          |
> | <br>  CREATE TABLE "FIDDLE_CGDJQPMDTXHHROBDNHLJ"."T" <br>   (        "ID" NUMBER(*,0)<br>   ) SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE <br>  PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 NOCOMPRESS LOGGING<br>  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645<br>  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1 BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)<br>  TABLESPACE "USERS"  |
> ```

> ```
> declare
>   f clob;
>   t clob;
> begin
>   f := dbms_metadata.get_ddl(
>     'FUNCTION',
>     'F'
>   );
>   t := dbms_metadata.get_ddl(
>     'TABLE',
>     'T'
>   );
>   
>   execute immediate 'drop table t';
>   execute immediate 'drop function f';
>   execute immediate t;
>   execute immediate f;
> end;
> /
> ```

> ```
> select *
> from v_ddl
> ```
>
> ```
> | DDL_                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   |
> | :--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- |
> | <br>  CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION "FIDDLE_CGDJQPMDTXHHROBDNHLJ"."F" <br>return number<br>is<br>begin<br>  return null;<br>end;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          |
> | <br>  CREATE TABLE "FIDDLE_CGDJQPMDTXHHROBDNHLJ"."T" <br>   (        "ID" NUMBER(*,0)<br>   ) SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE <br>  PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 NOCOMPRESS LOGGING<br>  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645<br>  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1 BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)<br>  TABLESPACE "USERS"  |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=f782ae46c116d6b5b63e3250c21f409d)*

Answer (score 0):

"Default after enabled ';' is added at end of each DDL."

is not true. For a PL/SQL unit, such as a function, it will include the "/" at the end of the returned value (as well as the semi-colons that are in the code block itself).

Depending on version, a CREATE VIEW that uses a WITH PLSQL declaration may terminate with a ";" and not the "/" which the sqplplus client expects, but that's an edge case

https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/SELECT.html#GUID-CFA006CA-6FF1-4972-821E-6996142A51C6